# how to set variable scope within the eventListener to be public ?

Tags: javascript, scope

i am trying to create a flag function to sending a signal when this flag function returns to false. But i only want this function returns false when my `mouseup`eventListener triggered, and i am confused about the variables inside the `eventListener` is not public scope. Here is the code sample:

```
<script>
var a = 11; 
//this will always return true and a is global variable
function flag(){
return a > 10;
} 

window.addEventListener("mouseup",function(){
    a = 5;  
   flag(); // this will return false and a comes to private only
});

function testFlag(){
    if(flag() == false){
    console.log("ok, i saw it");
    }
}

testFlag();
</script>
```

I am wondering how can i make the `testFlag()`running when the `mouseup`event triggered?

Comment: variable 'a' did not come private if you call it inside the eventListener. Can you clarify, what exactly do you want?

Comment: I am intend to change the value of 'a' and make the flag() return to false